# Debugging a nuget of an entire web installed into an empty web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget, visual-studio-debugging

We are in the middle of development for a core ASP.NET MVC web project and a customer plugin in the form of an MvcContrib plugin web project -- a web project injected into the core web as an area. The plugin is a soft reference in the core project, so it can be developed completely separately and dropped in.

*I am trying to generate a way to debug/code the plugin, so that the multiple custom plugins can be developed independent of the core web.*

The developers should only have to worry about coding and testing the plugin code. Also, I don't want them to change the core code in this custom plugin project -- that should be done in the core anyway.

I created the core web as a NuGet package and included all the necessary files so I could include it in a web.

My thinking was that I could create an empty web, install my core web, and the developers could have an F5-driven debugging environment.

I tested by creating a blank Mvc project, installed my core package and included one of my plugins. I changed the namespace of this empty web app to the namespace of the core web, thinking that Visual Studio debugging would properly attach and my core assembly.

Simple VS debugging in the empty app does not work -- I receive an HTTP Exception, most likely due to my routes not being registered. I also see that my log4net is not creating its logs folder, so I know the assembly's app start is not being called.

So I see that VS is not attaching to and calling my core assembly.

**Can I use this empty web as a host project for my nuget installed web and debug? If so, what configuration am I missing?**

**If not, how can I include the core web in each customer plugin project in such a way that I can drop my DLL into the bin and debug it?**

Using:
Visual Studio 2010

ASP.NET MVC2

Comment: Did you leave the `Global.asax` with its own `Application_Start` method in the empty web application? If you have code in the core app that needs to run on app start, it won't if the consuming app has its own app start method. Also, have you looked at Web Activator? We're building a similar setup and use it for startup code: http://nuget.org/packages/WebActivator/

Comment: Global.asax? Yeah: I thought of that. 

Actually, I removed everything -- including the web.config (because my version of Nuget ignores section elements in the configSource node on transform).

I don't know if I conveyed that the core app is a web. I want the web app (core) to run

Comment: If you haven't had any answers by the time I get into the office tomorrow morning I'll have a closer look at how we do things but it is possible because we're doing exactly that - creating a core framework as a nuget package and consuming it in multiple applications

Comment: I appreciate it. 

I will take a look at the WebActivator in an sec. I am currently trying various hacks to see how I can use an AfterBuild task to replace the DLL -- like name the throw-away Host app the same as the assembly as my core web app, then replace it.

Answer (score 0):

The way we are doing things that works pretty well is to use a combination of Web Activator and [Razor Generator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/) (available as a [Visual Studio extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1f6ec6ff-e89b-4c47-8e79-d2d68df894ec)). In order to access the views within the core web application, the consuming client application needs to know about them, either because they are all included as file references inside the Nuget package (messy) or because they are compiled into the core web dll. You can do that using Razor Generator. Once installed via Nuget you would need to change the `Custom Tool` property for each `.cshtml` file to `RazorGenerator`, which will create a `.generated.cs` file for each view. This will allow your sample client to use the layout and views from the core web application.

David Ebbo has some useful [blog posts on Razor Generator](http://blog.davidebbo.com/search/label/RazorGenerator)

Couple that with Web Activator to create a `PostActivationStartMethod` that runs your initialisation code (such as initialising `Log4Net`) and you should be good to go. We've had this running in 2 scenarios - consuming the framework package via Nuget and adding a project reference directly. Debugging was not working for the Nuget package consuming route but we don't include the pdb files in the Nuget package. We can debug when adding a project reference directly though.

Comment: Giving this a try. But I am going to start by seeing if PASM() can simply call core app's web start. I am hoping that I can make the empty-host web's MvcApplication be an empty shell that routes everything through core web app's MvcApplication.

Comment: How are you registering the routes and passing the handling of BeginRequests to your core app from the empty host? Can you post your Global.asax.cs -- or, a reasonable facsimile ;) ?